# Exporting Database with HTML from PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to export data from a Virtuemart installation into an excel file, so that it can be easily imported into Magento. The problem I'm having is that any fields containing HTML are causing line breaks and breaking the formatting of the file.

I've tried using semicolon as the delimiter as well as tab, but that didn't seem to address the issue because the odd line breaks were still there.

Is removing the line breaks and praying for it to work the only way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether the problem comes from unescaped commas or newlines in your CSV file, but either way there should be a means to properly escape them so they don't affect your import.

I'm also not quite clear what programs you're using in what ways; you've tagged this as phpMyAdmin and in the title ask about an export from phpMyAdmin, but reference Virtuemart and Magento in the post, so I'm guessing you're using phpMyAdmin to do the import/export of the database used by those other ecommerce programs.

Can I strongly suggest using the SQL file type instead?

Within phpMyAdmin, you can select custom values for "Lines terminated with" on both import and export for CSV files. Perhaps you can leverage that to make, for instance, `§` your line termination value. Incidentally, my understanding is that as long as each field is properly escaped ("Columns enclosed with" and/or "Columns escaped with"), an extra newline or comma in your content shouldn't matter to your import/export. Open up the exported file in a text editor and look at a few of the entries to make sure they're properly escaped and perhaps post a few lines that fail as an example here (obscuring any sensitive information, of course).